# Unable to use any JQuery methods attached to "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I console log "this", it show's the correct container and the correct HTML tree. When I try this.method(), it says this cannot be referenced in this context.

My goal is to to be able to target children of "this" where "this" is a div container. The problem I'm having is that the browser is refusing to recognize that it has children, even though it can do so when referenced without .children, or any of the jquery methods attached to it (this.val() or this.parent(), or etc.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script> 
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(id) {
            var contactCardNo = 0;
            var newVar = "";

            $(document).on('click', ".contact", function() {
                    alert(this);
                    console.log(this);
                    console.log($(this.children()));
                    /*if ($(newVar ).is(":hidden")) {
                        $(".contactDescription").hide();
                        $(newVar).show();
                    } else {
                        $(".contactDescription").show();
                        $(newVar).hide();
                    }*/
                });

            function attach_handler() {
                //$(newVar).click(function() {
                //    alert(this);
                //});
                //alert(newVar);
                var newVar = "\"" + newVar + "\"";
                alert(newVar);

            };

            $(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function() {
                var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
                var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
                var description = $("#description").val();
                var idToAttach = "#contact" + contactCardNo++;
                $("#contacts").append("<div class = 'contact'><p>" + firstName + "&nbsp" + lastName + "</p><p class = 'contactDescription'>Click for a description!</p><p class = 'description'>" + description + "</p></div>");
                $(idToAttach).css('width', '300px');
                $(idToAttach).css('height', '150px');
                $(idToAttach).css('display', 'block');
                newVar = idToAttach;
                attach_handler();
                $(idToAttach).hide();
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style type = "text/css">
            *{
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
            }
            #container{
                width:800px;
                height:800px;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            #contactForm {
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                display:inline-block;
                vertical-align:top;
            }
            #contacts {
                width:390px;
                height:800px;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            .contact {
                width:300px;
                height:150px;
                display:block;
            }
            .description {
                width: 280px;
                height: 100px;
            }
            div{
                border:1px solid #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container">
            <span>
                <div id = "contactForm">
                    <form>
                    <p>First Name: <input type = "text" name = "firstName" id = "firstName" /></p>
                    <p>Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type = "text" name = "lastName" id = "lastName" /></p>
                    <p>Description:</p>
                    <p><input type = "textarea" id = "description" /></p>
                    <p><input type = "button" value = "Add Contact" id = "submitButton" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id = "contacts">

                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your syntax: `this.children()` is no function, DOM Nodes have no `children()` method! That is a method of jquery, and should be used with a jQuery object, like `$(this)`

Answer (score 2):

for jQuery use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis can be tricky sometimes. You need to pass `this` to jQuery before running the `children()` method.

Change this:

```
console.log($(this.children()));
```

To this:

```
console.log($(this).children());
```